# Webmin seem to think Apache isn't started when it really is, how do I fix this?

Tags: 10.10, apache2, php

I performed a `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` on my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop for development purposes and then installed Webmin.  Now, Webmin doesn't seem to think Apache is running when it really is, and if I try to start Apache from the Webmin interface I get the following output:

```
Failed to start apache :

 :
 * Starting web server apache2
   ...done.
```

Also, through Webmin, if I try to view the Apache error log I get this:

```
cat: /var/log/apache2$SUFFIX/error.log: No such file or directory
```

Whatever is going on is preventing me from using name-based hosting to view local sites.  What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can been seen from the first paragraph of the webmin documentation on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebMin) and [Launchpad](https://answers.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/2873), webmin is no longer supported in Ubuntu. Instead, users are being pointed to [eBox](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/eBox). The same issue was reported on the forums and was determined to be an [issue with Webmin](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9951118) that needs to be resolved.

The issue was reported as a bug against Webmin here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3081423&group_id=17457&atid=117457

The fix seems to be to edit `/etc/apache2/envvars`, to quote jcameron:

> Ok, thanks .. I see the issue now. The fix is to remove $SUFFIX from the
>   lines :
>
> export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
>   export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
>   export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
>   export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
>
> as it will be empty anyway.

So you have 3 options:

1. Use eBox
2. Patch the file yourself to resolve the issue
3. Wait for the Webmin maintainer to fix the bug and new packages to be released.

Comment: Thanks, I found most of this information out after doing some independant research.  However, the news of Webmin no longer being supported by Ubuntu is new.